# Jboss 7 display image from hard dist

Tags: jboss, ftp, jboss7.x

I work with Jboss7 . I have files in home directory ( /home/user/images ).  I want to display this images in browser ,I other work I want Jboss 7 as FTP server.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can adapt this application to your needs. This is Free to use and modify under the terms of the GPL license

http://www.vonloesch.de/filebrowser.html

To restrict access to directories you can change:

```
// Allow browsing and file manipulation only in Un certain directories
private static final boolean RESTRICT_BROWSING = false;
// If true, the user is allowed to browse only in RESTRICT_PATH,
// if false, the user is allowed to browse all directories Besides RESTRICT_PATH
private static final boolean RESTRICT_WHITELIST = false;
// Paths, sperated by semicolon
// private static final String RESTRICT_PATH = "C: \\ CODE; E: \\"; // Win32: Case important !!
private static final String RESTRICT_PATH = "/ etc, / var";
```